# Codepen vs Local not matching up

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, codepen

I edited the settings in codepen to use bootstrap for css but it will not display page as it does locally.

Here is what the page looks like locally.
[image]

Here is the local code with the paragraph content shortened.

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome-4.6.1/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg">
        <style>
            body{
                margin: 50px;
                background-color: black;
            }
            .container{
                border: 3px solid red;
                width: 80%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container panel panel-default">
            <div class="row text-center">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                <h2>William "Bill" Paxton</h2>
                    <p><em>May 17, 1955 – February 25, 2017</em></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <figure class="figure text-center">
                <img src="images/download.jpeg" width="30%" alt="image of Bill Paxton">
                <figcaption class="figure-caption">An image of Bill Paxton</figcaption>
            </figure>
            <div class="well">
                <section>
                    <p>...</p>
                    <h3>Early Life</h3>
                    <p>...</p>
                    <h3>Career</h3>
                    <p>...</p>
                    <h3>Personal Life</h3>
                    <p>...</p>
                </section>
            </div>
            <div class="well">
                <section>
                    <h3>Click <a href="http://www.imdb.com/find?ref_=nv_sr_fn&q=bill+paxton&s=all" target="_blank">here</a> check out is filmography on IMDB</h3>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is what it looks like on codepen.

```
http://codepen.io/centem/pen/PbNbvR
```

What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default cdn that codepen.io uses for Bootstrap is for the Bootstrap 4 alpha. I've had problems with things not displaying properly as well.

Use this cdn instead:
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css

Comment: That did it cat! Thank you.